# How to use decorators to validate request and proceed else throw error

Tags: python, django, decorator

I wanted to know how can I use decorator to validate JSON request in django. Currently I have `validations.py` file with the function `validate` which returns `True` if request is valid else returns `False`.

My current implementation is like:

validations.py:

```
def validate(request):
   flag = True
   .... # Actual logic for validating request and 
        # sets flag to True/False
   return flag
```

views.py

```
from validations import validate

def authenticate_user(request):
     if validate(request):
        .......
        # executes further logic based on request
        # This checks if right access is present in Database
        # for the user or not. And hence I want to access request variable as it is
     else:
        return "Bad Request"
```

I wanted to know how exactly I can use decorator here and do something like this:

```
@validate
def authenticate_user(request):
    .......
    # executes further logic based on request
    # This checks if right access is present in Database
    # for the user or not. And hence I want to access request variable as it is
```

`validate` function should directly return `"Bad Request"` to the client if validations fails for any reason else normal code execution should happen.

Comment: You should rather write an authentication backend than writing decorators.

Comment: This is not just about authentication but many other custom views. I used it as an example only.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
import inspect

def decorator(f):

    def requestchecker(request, *args):
        if not validate(request):
            raise ValueError("bad request")
        return f(request, *args)
    return requestchecker


@decorator
def djangoview(request, x, y):
    # do stuff
```

Of course, the actual code should be slightly modified, depending on whether you use named or positional argument etc...

Answer (score 1):

First point: your validation function should not return a boolean flag (which tells you nothing about what went wrong), but raise an exception (possibly a `ValidationError` or your own custom exception type, depending on what you're validating exactly) - the caller being in charge of catching it and doing what seems appropriate with it.

Second point: your view should not return the litteral string "Bad request", it should return an `HttpResponse` with the appropriate status code. FWIW, the http status code for "Bad Request" is 400, but it has a very well defined semantic (emphasis is mine):

> The request could not be understood by the server due to **malformed
>   syntax**. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

A missing field in a JSON payload is NOT a "malformed syntax".

As for how to use a decorator to apply a same validation function to more than a single view function, assuming your `validate` function raises a `ValidationError` (or any more specific exception type you defined):

```
def require_validation(func):
   def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            validate(request)
        except ValidationError as e:
            # logging the exception might be useful
            # and you may want to select the exact
            # response status depending on the exact error
            # Also if your client posted some json stuff
            # chances are it expects a json content-type and body
            return HttpResponse("Bad request", status=400)

        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)

    wrapper.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrapper.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrapper

@require_validation
def myview(request, ...):
    #...
```

Comment: I totally agree with your inputs regarding JSON response and HttpResponse. I use the same in my application. I kept sample code simple for easy understanding. I shall try out your solution about decorators.

Answer (score 0):

You also can do with this..

```
from yourmodel.models import Admin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def admin_required(function):
    """
    @admin_required
    def dashboard(request):
        #do_stuff
    """
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated() and \
                Admin.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```